# Why wouldn't global variable parse correctly with Master Config?

Tags: config, focus-lab-master-config, global-variables

Using Focus Lab's Master Config, I've set a test global variable for production, like so:

```
$env_global['global_test'] = 'test';
```

Then in an embedded template I've dropped in `{global_test}`. Also tried it in a non-embedded template.

In both cases the output, regardless of environment, is this;

```
{global_test}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angie,

I looked through our config code and what you've done *should* work. Can you confirm that you're editing the right environment file to be sure?

I'm reading this from my phone so when I get to my desk later I'll run a few tests to see what's up.

Comment: I'm at my phone too, I'll double check the environment file when I get a chance. Pretty sure it's the right one but I'll check again.

Comment: Question - does the GV have to be present on all of the environment files? That's the only way I got it to work.

Comment: No, the GV only needs to be in the appropriate environment file. I tested locally and got it working as expected so this leads me to believe you may have some streams crossed environment-wise.

Can you share a gist/pastie/etc of the following: config.master.php, config.env.php & the environment you're working in? (Obviously feel free to remove any sensitive data you don't want to be shared). Also please share the root URL you're testing on.

Comment: Was most likely a host / server setup issue. Don't know what was going on with their previous server setup, but we got the site switched to something we have more control over and it's working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue yesterday and the **facepalm moment** was when I realized I had added my variable to config.dev.php when I should have added it to config.local.php.

Are you certain it's not a similar situation?

Perhaps double check the case statements in config.env.php to ensure the matching is working.